# Failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c mvn package" in CI/CD (Database connection issue)

Tags: docker, github, github-actions

I want to build and deploy the container of the project to Docker Hub. I have a problem when I look through its build process in GitHub Actions.

I use `mr-smithers-excellent/docker-build-push@v5` for docker

Here is the repo : [Link](https://github.com/mr-smithers-excellent/docker-build-push)

It throws the issue shown below:

```
#14 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c mvn package" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
------
 > [build 5/5] RUN mvn package:
Error: ERROR] 
Error: ERROR] Please refer to /target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
Error: ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
Error: ERROR] -> [Help 1]
Error: ERROR] 
Error: ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Error: ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
Error: ERROR] 
Error: ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
Error: ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
------
Dockerfile:12
--------------------
  10 |     
  11 |     # Build the project and create the executable JAR
  12 | >>> RUN mvn package
  13 |     
  14 |     # Stage 2: Run stage
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c mvn package" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
Error: Command failed: docker build -f Dockerfile -t docker.io/***/bookdelivery:latest .
```

Edited

I also got this error message .

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

How can I fix it?

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
# Stage 1: Build stage
FROM maven:3.8.4-openjdk-17-slim AS build

# Copy Maven files for dependency resolution
COPY pom.xml ./
COPY .mvn .mvn

# Copy application source code
COPY src src

# Build the project and create the executable JAR
RUN mvn package

# Stage 2: Run stage
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim

# Set working directory
WORKDIR bookdelivery

# Copy the JAR file from the build stage
COPY --from=build target/*.jar bookdelivery.jar

# Expose port 1221
EXPOSE 1221

# Set the entrypoint command for running the application
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "bookdelivery.jar"]
```

Here is the workflow file:

```
name: CI/CD Pipeline

## The following codes trigger the pipeline when the code is pushed on the main branch.

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  test:
    name: Unit Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'temurin'
          cache: 'maven'

      - name: Build with Maven
        run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml

      - name: Cache Maven packages
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ~/.m2
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-m2-${{ hashFiles('**/pom.xml') }}
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-m2

      - name: Run Tests
        run: mvn -B test

  build-and-push:
    name: Build and Push
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'temurin'
          cache: 'maven'

      - name: Build with Maven
        run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml

      - name: Dockerize & Push Docker Image
        uses: mr-smithers-excellent/docker-build-push@v5
        with:
          image: noyandocker/bookdelivery
          tags: latest
          registry: docker.io
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
```

Here is the repo : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/bookdelivery)

Comment: Does this Dockerfile works as expected locally?  a failing package goal would be just shadowing a compilation error. either try to build the image locally or re-run the failing github action with debu enabled.

Comment: @Sombriks I can run this command `mvn clean install` and `docker-compose up -d` with out any problem.

Comment: maybe the action you are using to create the image is missing something needed to compile the project. you could try to use the already packaged version from the previous step and make the docker image use it to build the image. Thiis action does that: https://gist.github.com/sombriks/c8e8979d80efaf02de6bf04ffe5805cc and the Dockerfile referenced is this one: https://gist.github.com/sombriks/2c810d07eca883dba179377be515b6cf

Comment: @Sombriks Here is the source : https://github.com/Rapter1990/bookdelivery/blob/main/.github/workflows/ci-cd.yml

Comment: read my gists and try to ditch out the build step from your Dockerfile. your workflow already builds the jar, why waste time building it again?

Comment: @Sombriks My ci/cd file is different. I used `mr-smithers-excellent` to build and publish the docker image as I said before.

Comment: so change your faulty workflow file. my suggestion is to build the image using the already packaged jar created in previous steps. see the workflow file i provided as example so you can base your changes on a working, production ready example.

Comment: @Sombriks I found this message `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`

Comment: @Sombriks I revised docker-compose, Dockerfile and application.yml but nothing changed. I got MySQL issue in testcontainer and it throws `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately with the current information no one will be able to help here. There are at least two problems here, only one of which can be directly resolved.

First of all you aren't using the standard docker package publish action. You can see a working example of the docker/build-push-action we have in this [authress local build pipeline](https://github.com/Authress/authress-local/blob/release/0.1/.github/workflows/build.yml#L93).

The relevant parts are:

```yaml
- name: DockerHub - Container registry login
  uses: docker/login-action@65b78e6e13532edd9afa3aa52ac7964289d1a9c1
  with:
    registry: ${{ env.DOCKER_HUB_REGISTRY }}
    username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME }}
    password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD }}

- name: Build and push Docker image
  uses: docker/build-push-action@f2a1d5e99d037542a71f64918e516c093c6f3fc4
```

But the real issue has nothing to do with docker at all, the and error you get tells you that:

```
------
 > [build 5/5] RUN mvn package:
Error: ERROR] 
Error: ERROR] Please refer to /target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
Error: ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
Error: ERROR] -> [Help 1]
Error: ERROR] 
Error: ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Error: ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
Error: ERROR] 
Error: ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
Error: ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
------
```

Specifically, you can see the recommendation in that error message:

```
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

So update your dockerfile, and change `RUN mvn package` to `RUN mvn package -Xe`. And then update your post with the included error details.

Comment: I changed `RUN mvn package`  to `RUN mvn package -X` and I only saw ` `Please refer to /target/surefire-reports for the individual test results and failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c mvn package -X" did not complete successfully`

Comment: I revised docker-compose, Dockerfile and application.yml but nothing changed. I got MySQL issue in testcontainer and it throws `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`

Answer (score 0):

please take a look at [this PR](https://github.com/Rapter1990/bookdelivery/pull/1).

Noteworthy:

1 - don't package your project twice. the github action already packages your project so it's just a waste of image layers to make packaging responsibility of docker to do so. use a smaller, thinner, docker build file that expects the jar file to be built already:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jre-alpine

ARG SERVICE=bookdelivery
ARG VERSION=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

ENV SERVICE=$SERVICE
ENV VERSION=$VERSION

ADD ./target/$SERVICE-$VERSION.jar /$SERVICE-$VERSION.jar

ENTRYPOINT java -jar /$SERVICE-$VERSION.jar
```

2 - tag your images properly. one thing is to always use the `latest` version on your tests and development images, another one completely different is to put those dangling pointers in production. pin a specific version on the images you'll put in production.

Even more important, if you are **authoring** an image, don't just tag it as *latest*. use proper tag versions, so if anyone needs to rollback a deployment to the previous running, stable version, it will be known. the action i first sent as example to you had this approach, the one in the PR has it too:

```
  # This step is tailored specifically for docker hub,
  # see the action docs for other registries
  - name: Build and publish image on Docker hub
    uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
    with:
      context: .
      build-args: |
        SERVICE=${{ env.SERVICE_NAME }}
        VERSION=${{ env.GIT_TAG }}
      file: ${{ env.DOCKERFILE }}
      tags: ${{ env.DOCKER_USERNAME }}/${{ env.SERVICE_NAME }}:${{ env.GIT_TAG }} , ${{ env.DOCKER_USERNAME }}/${{ env.SERVICE_NAME }}:latest
      push: true
```

If you want to know more about this action, read the action logs in my fork, i ran it a couple of times so you can see both failure logs and success logs.

Comment: I want to share some screenshots. ibb.co/QfHZSdg ibb.co/tp9Q9Pk . As you can see, ControllerTest cannot work because it needs to connect mysql database through test container.

Comment: just checkout my fork, or even care to look at the github action logs. every single test is passing. if it does what is supposed to do is another story, fix one problem at time. for example, you want imaes on docker ub? it's solved, documented. you had just one test not extending the base testcase which configures the testcontainers, all other thests looks fine. check out my fork.